# How to pass type to FormGroup?

Tags: angular, angular8

I use this code to build form fields:

```
this._form = this._builder.group(
      {
        code: [null, [Validators.required]],
        startDate: [null, [Validators.required]],
        finishDate: [null, []],
        name: [null, []],
        shortName: [null, []],
        linkFieldId: [null, [Validators.required]]
      }
    );
```

I need that all fields of form will be type

```
IFields {
    code: string,
    ....
}
```

Because after I want to get property any like:

```
return this._form.value.code
```

I tried this:

```
return this._form.values as IFields;
```

Comment: Is the "this._builder" a FormBuilder Type https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Reactive forms are not typed and the value will always be any. So the

```
return this._form.value as IFields;
```

or

```
return (this._form.value as IFields).code;
```

is correct solution.

Additionaly, you can type the form setup (but only to check that you've setup all the fields you needed and prevent typos) - without effect on the value type:

```
this._form = this._builder.group(
      {
        code: [null, [Validators.required]],
        startDate: [null, [Validators.required]],
        finishDate: [null, []],
        name: [null, []],
        shortName: [null, []],
        linkFieldId: [null, [Validators.required]]
      } as { [k in keyof IFields]: any }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass type to FormGroup. Though you can use Regex Angular validators which may be close to what you want to achieve.